# How can I edit the email sent when a new comment is received?

Tags: comments, notifications

I have a multi author site and when a user comments on a post, that author gets an email saying there is a new comment. This email is formated in the standard WordPress way

```
New comment on your post "Test post for comment testing"
Author : Person (IP: 0.0.0.0 , netowrk) E-mail : email@example.com
URL    : 
Whois  : 
Comment: 
Test

You can see all comments on this post here: 
http://example.com/test-post

Permalink: http://example.com/test-post
```

The site doesn't utilize URLs in the comment field so this is always blank. I'd also like to remove WHOIS and IP and network details, leaving the commenters name and email.

How can I edit this? Preferably without a plugin if possible.

Comment: What have you actually tried, you need to hook into `comment_notification_text`

Comment: @Wyck I haven't tried anything because I have absolutely no idea where to look and all my Googling has resulted in unrelated results. But now I know to look into comment_notification_text some more. Ta.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `comment_notification_text` filter is in `wp-includes/pluggable.php` in the `wp_notify_postauthor` function. You can copy and paste the `$notify_message` stuff and edit out what you don't want.

```
function wpd_comment_notification_text( $notify_message, $comment_id ){
    // get the current comment and post data
    $comment = get_comment( $comment_id );
    $post = get_post( $comment->comment_post_ID );
    // don't modify trackbacks or pingbacks
    if( '' == $comment->comment_type ){
        // build the new message text
        $notify_message  = sprintf( __( 'New comment on your post "%s"' ), $post->post_title ) . "\r\n";
        $notify_message .= sprintf( __('Author : %1$s'), $comment->comment_author ) . "\r\n";
        $notify_message .= sprintf( __('E-mail : %s'), $comment->comment_author_email ) . "\r\n";
        $notify_message .= sprintf( __('URL    : %s'), $comment->comment_author_url ) . "\r\n";
        $notify_message .= __('Comment: ') . "\r\n" . $comment->comment_content . "\r\n\r\n";
        $notify_message .= __('You can see all comments on this post here: ') . "\r\n";
        $notify_message .= get_permalink($comment->comment_post_ID) . "#comments\r\n\r\n";
        $notify_message .= sprintf( __('Permalink: %s'), get_comment_link( $comment_id ) ) . "\r\n";

        if ( user_can( $post->post_author, 'edit_comment', $comment_id ) ) {
            if ( EMPTY_TRASH_DAYS )
                $notify_message .= sprintf( __('Trash it: %s'), admin_url("comment.php?action=trash&c=$comment_id") ) . "\r\n";
            else
                $notify_message .= sprintf( __('Delete it: %s'), admin_url("comment.php?action=delete&c=$comment_id") ) . "\r\n";
            $notify_message .= sprintf( __('Spam it: %s'), admin_url("comment.php?action=spam&c=$comment_id") ) . "\r\n";
        }
    }
    // return the notification text
    return $notify_message;
}
add_filter( 'comment_notification_text', 'wpd_comment_notification_text', 20, 2 );
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I've learned something new today! :)